# Pass array from javascript file to another and then output to html

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm thinking about an algorithm like this:

1) get array of strings from a json url

2) pass the array of strings into another file to add attributes to it

3) call the second javascript file as a script in an html file to output it

I've been trying to write smaller programs to accomplish this but the best I have gotten was either from step 1 to step 2 or step 2 to step 3 but never all three steps.

first.js

```
document.write("before request") //everything before the require will output to html
var request = require('request');
document.write("after request") //everything after the require will not output to html

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
},
function getArray(error, response, body)
{
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        //do stuff with json file
        //push strings into an array
    }
}
```

second.js

```
var img = new Image();
function outputHtml(array)
{
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        img.src = array[i];
        img.setAttribute("width" , "300");
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<script src = "..\second.js"></script>
<script src = "..\first.js"></script>
```

Can you guys give me tips on what I can do to my code to accomplish this or if I should change my algorithm? I'm trying to transition to javascript from c++ but I'm not sure if my algorithm is completely wrong or not

Comment: You aren't calling requesting first.js from second.js? I'm confused about exactly what you're trying to do. If this is an electron thing, and first.js and second.js represent separate window processes, you can pass the result using electron's `ipc`, if first.js represents a remote nodejs server, you will have to send a http request from second.js. If both files will be directly included in index.html, just include them in order and use the outputHtml function inside of getArray (which doesn't require a name i.e you can just have "function(err,res,body){...})". Can you clarify the context here?

Comment: I tried to use outputHtml inside of getArray and it worked but when I tried to call the script inside of index.html, I got an error. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the message right now because I don't have access to my pc, but I think the error was caused because I can't have .js files require anything if they are being called by index.html. Not sure if this is true but I saw something similar earlier while googling.

Comment: You can import with script tags and use a module loader in the same file without any problem, just make sure you import using script tags in the correct order (The order they depend on one another).. So in this case you would put the <script> import for second.js before first.js. Additionally, if you load your scripts in your index.html header, they may execute before the DOM has loaded, so you may need to wrap whatever functionality you want to run once the page has loaded in document.addEventListener("load",function(e){...}), or move your <script> imports to the bottom of your document.

Comment: I just updated my first.js with how im testiing it. Everything before the require request statement works, but after the require statement, it doesn' twork anymore. Is my require statement wrong or something

Comment: Does your electron/browserwindow console say anything? Do you have the `request` module installed with npm? Also you should try not to use document.write, it is unreliable and can result in some odd behavior. You can open the dev-tools/console by using the toggleDevTools() method of your browser window in your main process.

Comment: rather, use console.log or even alerts to give you debugging feedback